# MSBuild batch updating ItemGroup MetaData with output from a custom task

Tags: msbuild, build-automation, msbuildextensionpack

I am trying to use MSBuild 4.0 to Uninstall\install a set of windows services I have defined in an ItemGroup using the MSBuild extensions.  The problem I am running into is if the service does not exist the uninstall TaskAction will error out.  I want to be able to use the CheckExists TaskAction to set a flag in my metadata that I can evaluate on the condition statement.

However, I cannot figure out how to batch over the list of services, calling the CheckExist task and updating the flag in my metadata.  See sample below:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ServiceName Include="Service1">
      <ExeName>Service1.exe</ExeName>
      <ServicePath>$(LocalBin)\Service1.exe</ServicePath>
      <User>LocalSystem</User>
      <Exists></Exists>
    </ServiceName>
    <ServiceName Include="Service2">
      <ExeName>Service2.exe</ExeName>
      <ServicePath>$(LocalBin)\Service2.exe</ServicePath>
      <User>LocalSystem</User>
      <Exists></Exists>
    </ServiceName>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="UninstallServices">

    <!--how can I batch over this command to set %(ServiceName.Exist)-->
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Computer.WindowsService TaskAction="CheckExists" ServiceName="%(ServiceName.Identity)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Exists" PropertyName="DoesExist"/>
    </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Computer.WindowsService>

    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Computer.WindowsService TaskAction="Uninstall" ServiceName="%(ServiceName.Identity)" User="%(ServiceName.User)" ServicePath="%(ServiceName.ServicePath)" Condition="%(ServiceName.Exists) = 'True'" />
  </Target>
```

I have done some searching and have not found an example where metadata is being updated based on an Output result of a Task.  Is this something that is possible?  Should I be taking a different approach?

My current solution for this problem has been to set ContinueOnError to true on the call for the uninstall, but I do not like this approach because I could be hiding other errors.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Tyson Moncrief